# A persistent warning when using //nolint:godox in Golang

Tags: linter, golangci-lint

```
WARN [runner/nolint] Found unknown linters in //nolint directives: godox todo: fix once roles are in place
```

This warning keeps coming up when I am building my Golang project. What does this mean?
What is the meaning of unknown linters here?
I already have godox enabled in my config file for the linter but this warning doesn't seem to be going away.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution to this.
I was using a nolint:godox on a todo comment and it was formatted as follows.

`//nolint:godox TODO: blah blah..`

Which will throw out a warning. So we need to separate the comment from the actual nolint statement.
The correct way to do it is as follows:

`//nolint:godox //TODO: blah blah..`